# Highlighting and Replacing Text

Tags: excel, vba, keystroke

I'm trying to eliminate a long series of repetitive keystrokes.

I'm taking text in the form:

> "XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX (XXXX XXXXX XXXXXXX)"

And removing the bit at the end, making it:

> "XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX"

I'm using the keystrokes: F2, Shift+Ctrl+RtArrow, Shift+Ctrl+RtArrow, Shift+Ctrl+RtArrow, Shift+RtArrow, Backspake, Enter

I tried recording this sequence of keystrokes with Excel's Record Macro function. If I run the recorded macro on the next cell, containing "YYYYYYYY YYYYYYYYY (YYYY YYYYYY YYYYYYYY)", it doesn't perform the keystrokes I recorded, it replaces the contents of the cell with the resulting contents of the cell I recorded the macro in, "XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX".

The code Excel generated was this, in which it appears to have ignored the keystrokes I performed, and just copies the result:

```
Sub DelProcVintage()
'
' DelProcVintage Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+j
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Is there a way to issue my keystroke sequence through a macro?

Comment: use `SendKeys`
[Excel VBA - SendKeys Method](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html)

Comment: Also, when you say you're converting `XXXX XXX (XXX XX XXX)` to `XXXX XXX`, are you basically removing everything after the `(`?  If so, then this might be a better resource for you [Remove Text Before/After Character](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1783-excel-remove-text-before-character.html)

Comment: `ActiveCell.Value = Trim(Split(ActiveCell.Value,"(")(0))`

Comment: Thank you, both of those suggestions help!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying some code I found. It gets me about 80% there, which saves a lot of repetitive keystrokes. I modified this code to remove the last 25 characters of a string. There are some bits that have more or fewer than 25 characters, but there are so few, it's pretty easy to spot them and make fixes.

```
Sub delEnd()
'
' delEnd Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+j
'
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim xChar As String
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Macro Options"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address,     Type:=8)
'xChar = Application.InputBox("String", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    xValue = Rng.Value
    Rng.Value = VBA.Left(xValue, VBA.Len(xValue) - 25)
'25 characters is the most common length of the text I am removing
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you take a new column and put a formula like:

```
=Left('cell',10)
```

the left formula cuts everything from the right after a number of numbers, then if you want to make a macro (Example row 1 to 500):

```
Range("D1:D500").FormulaR1C1 = "(Formula)"
```

Then copy paste value and delete original column